# Migrating xml data

Tags: c#, xml

I have 2 xml file formats (the old schema and a new schema for an upcoming release). My question is; what’s the easiest way to migrate the data? Can I used XSLT some how? I am using C# but the BCL XslCompiledTransform Load method only seems to accept 1 file as an argument. Can anyone post an example to do this?

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tutorial on how to do it.

http://www.csharpfriends.com/Articles/getArticle.aspx?articleID=63